# EuropassCV: Removing the square and links

Tags: europasscv

The [EuropassCV template](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv) is a nice template for writing CVs. I would like to do the following modifications to suit my needs:

1. Removing all links to mails/webpages, so that it becomes just a plain, simple PDF;
2. Removing the square at the end of the horizontal lines separating sections.

I believe this can be done by modifying the `europasscv.cls` file, but I am not expert enough to easily navigate it.

MWE

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}

\ecvname{Betty Smith}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com}
\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

  \ecvpersonalinfo

  \ecvsection{Work experience}

  \ecvtitle{Year -- Year}{Text.}
  \ecvitem{}{Text.}
  \ecvitem{}{Text.}

  \end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

**NOTE**: I am searching for an answer which does not involve `\RenewDocumentCommand`, since it does not compile (my version of TeX is updated, as shown in the edit). A modification of the `europasscv.cls` achieving the same effect is also acceptable.

**EDIT**: Error message:

[image: Error Message]

Updated version:

[image]

**EDIT 2**: [Log file](https://files.fm/u/sykmmv8k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove all links to mails/webpages, so that it becomes just a plain, simple PDF. Well, that is a problem, because it depends on your used viewer: some of the pdf viewer are able to recognize webpages and mails and create and create the correct link for them ...

But you can try with adding in your preamble:

```
\hypersetup{draft} % <==================================================
%\def\convertstring#1{#1}
\def\processlinks#1{#1}
```

To remove the square at the end of the horizontal lines separating sections you can simply redefine the used command `ecvsection` like this:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\RenewDocumentCommand\ecvsection{o+m}{%
  \@ecvitemcommandfalse
  \ecvupdatecurrentskip{#1}{\bigskipamount}
  \setlength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{\ecv@rightcolwidth}
  %\addtolength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{-7pt}
  \ecvitem{\ecvsectionstyle{#2}}
          {\textcolor{ecvrulecolor}{\noindent\rule{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{1pt}}}
  \nopagebreak
  \@ecvoverrideskiptrue
  \setlength{\ecv@currentskip}{\medskipamount}
}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

So with the following MWE

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\ecvname{Katie Smith}
\ecvaddress{12 Strawberry Hill, Dublin 8 Éire/Ireland}
\ecvmobile{+353 555 123 555}
\ecvtelephone{+353 127 6689}
\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{smith@kotmail.com another@email.com}
\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
% \ecvgithubpage{www.github.com/smith}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}

\ecvdateofbirth{1 March 1975}
\ecvnationality{Irish}
\ecvgender{Female}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

% \date{}

\hypersetup{draft} % <==================================================
%\def\convertstring#1{#1}
\def\processlinks#1{#1}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\RenewDocumentCommand\ecvsection{o+m}{%
  \@ecvitemcommandfalse
  \ecvupdatecurrentskip{#1}{\bigskipamount}
  \setlength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{\ecv@rightcolwidth}
  %\addtolength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{-7pt}
  \ecvitem{\ecvsectionstyle{#2}}
          {\textcolor{ecvrulecolor}{\noindent\rule{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{1pt}}}
  \nopagebreak
  \@ecvoverrideskiptrue
  \setlength{\ecv@currentskip}{\medskipamount}
}
\makeatother % <========================================================



\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

  \ecvpersonalinfo

  \ecvbigitem{Job applied for}{European project manager}

  \ecvsection{Work experience}

  \ecvtitle{August 2002 -- Present}{Independent consultant}
  \ecvitem{}{National Youth Council of Ireland\newline 3 Montague Street, Dublin 2, D02 V327, Ireland}
  \ecvitem{}{Evaluation of European Commission youth training support measures for youth national agencies and young people}

  \ecvtitle{March 2002 -- July 2002}{Internship}
  \ecvitem{}{European Commission, Youth Unit, DG Education and Culture \newline 200, Rue de la Loi, 1049 Brussels (Belgium)}
  \ecvitem{}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
      \item evaluating youth training programmes and the partnership between the Council of Europe and European Commission
      \item organizing and running a 2 day workshop on non-formal education for Action 5 large scale projects focusing on quality, assessment and recognition
      \item contributing to the steering sroup on training and developing action plans on training for the next 3 years. Working on the Users Guide for training and the support measures
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }
  \ecvitem{}{\ecvhighlight{Business or sector}\quad European institution}

  \ecvtitle{Oct 2001 -- Feb 2002}{Researcher / Independent Consultant}
  \ecvitem{}{Council of Europe, Budapest (Hungary)}
  \ecvitem{}{Working in a research team carrying out in-depth qualitative evaluation of the 2 year Advanced Training of Trainers in Europe using participant observations, in-depth interviews and focus groups. Work carried out in training courses in Strasbourg, Slovenia and Budapest.}


  \ecvsection{Education and training}

  \ecvtitlelevel{1997--2001}{PhD - Thesis Title: 'Young People in the Construction of the Virtual University’, Empirical research on e-learning}{ISCED~6}
  \ecvitem{}{Trinity College Dublin, The University of Dublin, Ireland}

  \ecvtitle{1993--1997}{Bachelor of Science in Sociology and Psychology}
  \ecvitem{}{Trinity College Dublin, The University of Dublin, Ireland}
  \ecvitem{}{
      \begin{ecvitemize}
    \item sociology of risk
    \item sociology of scientific knowledge / information society
    \item anthropology
    \item E-learning and Psychology
    \item research methods
      \end{ecvitemize}
  }

  \pagebreak

  \ecvsection{Personal skills}
  \ecvmothertongue{English}
  \ecvlanguageheader
  \ecvlanguage{French}{C1}{C2}{B2}{C1}{C2}
  \ecvlanguagecertificate{Diplôme d'études en langue française (DELF) B1}
  \ecvlastlanguage{German}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}
  \ecvlanguagefooter

  \ecvblueitem{Communication skills}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
    \item team work: I have worked in various types of teams from research teams to national league hockey. For 2 years I coached my university hockey team
    \item mediating skills: I work on the borders between young people, youth trainers, youth policy and researchers, for example running a 3 day workshop at CoE Symposium ``Youth Actor of Social Change'', and my continued work on youth training programmes 
    \item intercultural skills: I am experienced at working in a European dimension such as being a rapporteur at the CoE Budapest ``youth against violence seminar'' and working with refugees.
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }

  \ecvblueitem{Organisational / managerial skills}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
    \item whilst working for a Brussels based refugee NGO ``Convivial'' I organized a ``Civil Dialogue'' between refugees and civil servants at the European Commission 20th June 2002
    \item during my PhD I organised a seminar series on research methods
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }

  \ecvdigitalcompetence{\ecvBasic}{\ecvIndependent}{\ecvProficient}{\ecvIndependent}{\ecvBasic}

  \ecvblueitem{Computer skills}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
    \item competent with most Microsoft Office programmes
    \item experience with HTML
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }


  \ecvblueitem{Other skills}{Creating pieces of Art and visiting Modern Art galleries. Enjoy all sports particularly hockey, football and running. Love to travel and experience different cultures.}

  \ecvblueitem{Driving licence}{A, B}

  \ecvsection{Additional information}

  \ecvblueitem{Publications}{\textit{How to do Observations: Borrowing techniques from the Social Sciences to help Participants do Observations in Simulation Exercises}, Coyote EU/CoE Partnership Publication, (2002).
}

  \end{europasscv}

\end{document}
```

you will get the following result:

[image]

## EDIT:

There are several versions out of this class. It seems you are using an older one (see beta remark in the log file).

Please change my given code

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\RenewDocumentCommand\ecvsection{o+m}{%
  \@ecvitemcommandfalse
  \ecvupdatecurrentskip{#1}{\bigskipamount}
  \setlength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{\ecv@rightcolwidth}
  %\addtolength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{-7pt}
  \ecvitem{\ecvsectionstyle{#2}}
          {\textcolor{ecvrulecolor}{\noindent\rule{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{1pt}}}
  \nopagebreak
  \@ecvoverrideskiptrue
  \setlength{\ecv@currentskip}{\medskipamount}
}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

to the new code

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand{\ecvsection}[2][1.3\bigskipamount]{%
  \@ecvitemcommandfalse
  \setlength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{\ecv@rightcolwidth}
% \addtolength{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{-7pt}
  \ecvitem[#1]{\ecvsectionstyle{#2}}
              {\textcolor{ecvrulecolor}{\noindent\rule{\ecv@sectionrulelength}{1pt}}}
  \nopagebreak
  \@ecvitemskipfalse
  \@ecvlastitemwassectiontrue
  \vspace*{\medskipamount}
}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

If that does not help please add the curretd definition of command `\ecvsection` to your question ...

Comment: Unfortunately, the square-removal code gives me the following error:
Undefined control sequence, referred to `\RenewDocumentCommand`

Comment: I compile with TeXShop. I will add the complete error message in a moment.

Comment: Please update your TeX distribution. I'm using current MiKTeX (with windows) in version: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)`. My version is `.19` instead your `.16` ...

Comment: I have updated my TeX distribution, as can be seen from the new image in the question. No newer version is available. The same error still persists.

Comment: Sure. Link to the complete log file in the EDIT 2 of question.

Comment: It worked (finally!). Thank you very much! You were really helpful.